# Image-upload iOS

Tags: php, ios, file-upload

I'm trying since some hours to upload a jpg-image to my server. I found loads of questions and solutions about that topic but I didn't get it work. 
This is what i got so far:

XCODE:

```
 - (void) upload {
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img ,90);
long imageSize = (long)[imageData length];
NSLog(@"SIZE OF IMAGE: %.2f Mb", (float)imageSize/1024/1024);


NSString *urlString = @"http://www.MYURL.com/upload.php";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]] ;
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n"dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@data",returnString);
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$target_path = "./";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['picture']['name']);  

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {  
echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['picture']['name'])." has been uploaded";  
} else{  
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";  
}
?>
```

I set the full permissions to the directory on the server so that shouldn't be the error.

Some help with this problem would make me really really lucky!!!

Comment: What do you get in the file `NSLog`? Is there anything in your server logs?

Comment: Why are you not passing an NSError to sendSynchronousRequest and then examining the result?

Comment: and where is your PHP server side code, `filename=\".jpg\"` ???

Comment: I think the HTTP Content-Type header should be 'multipart/mixed; boundary="..."' may be part of your problem.  You also may need to set the body section Content-Type to image/jpeg.  In any case giving us both the NSError returned and the server return string would help a lot.

Comment: Where exactly should I set "multipart/mixed"?
like -> 
         NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/mixed; boundary=%@",boundary];
<--???